# Captcha code validation not working

Tags: php, captcha

I have the following code **validation** php script:

```
  if(empty($_POST['captcha_code'])) {
    $error = 1;
    $code[3] = 'color:#FF0000;';
  } else {
    include_once "formfiles/captcha.php";
        $randomnr = new Securimage();
    $valid = $randomnr->check($_POST['captcha_code']);

    if(!$valid) {
      $error = 1;
      $code[3] = 'color:#FF0000;';   
      $code[4] = '<strong><span style="color:#FF0000;">Incorrect code</span></strong>';
    }
  }
```

and this **captcha** php code:

```
<?php
    Securimage(); 
    exit(); 

    function Securimage() 
    { 
    $randomnr = rand(1000, 9999);
    $_SESSION['randomnr2'] = md5($randomnr);

    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 38);

    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 150, 150, 150);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

    imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 200, 35, $black);

    //path to font - this is just an example you can use any font you like:

    $font = dirName(__FILE__).'/calvin.ttf';

    imagettftext($im, 20, 4, 22, 30, $grey, $font, $randomnr);

    imagettftext($im, 20, 4, 15, 32, $white, $font, $randomnr);

    imagegif($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
    }
?>
```

After submitting my form I always get an awkward bit of code starting with gif. Where is my fault? Can somebody please help me?

Comment: how is the check method working?

Comment: `imagegif($im)` will output the raw .gif image bytes to the browser. Without an appropriate content-type header (e.g. `image/gif`), the browser will just see it as plain text and try to display it as such. If that script's linked to directly, and not via an `<img src="...">`, you'll never get anything but binary garbage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decalare header about the content type to browser recognize it as image. Try this

```
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
Securimage(); 
exit();
```

Comment: I always get the error message cannot modify header information. How can I fix this issue??

Comment: make sure you dont have any `space` blank before `<?php` or after `?>` tag.